# Would + infinitive?

Tags: tense, grammaticality

> 'Since then she would be nice. And when she would come back home with her tired children, she would
> crouch for a while and would say that she loves them'

How can you English people know that I mean kind of 'used to' and not what-ifs? Or maybe isn't that understood? Would have + third column be more appropriate?

Comment: Because there is no inversion and no interrogative punctuation, as in "Since then, would she be nice?" In spoken English the inversion isn't always applied, but the intonation would reveal that it is a question.

Comment: @WeatherVane ok but what if doesn't have to be questioning.

Comment: Please give an example of 'what-if' usage that isn't a question.

Comment: @WeatherVane I mean kinda "Kate could be nicer, but she isn't and she wasn't"

Comment: That isn't a usage of 'would' as the question asks, and I don't really understand it. What is a 'third column'? Your example sentence in the question contains three 'woulds' where it only needs one: "And when she came back home with her tired children, she would crouch for a while and say that she loves them."

Comment: @WeatherVane Third column I mean verb from past participle. I don't mean "when she came back home...", I mean "she would come back home..." so that coming home was repetitive, too

Comment: The repetition is implied by the use of the single 'would' that I showed. You can't say it like that when there was only one occurrence.

Comment: @WeatherVane oh, you're right, I mean "Kate would be nicer, but she isn't and she wasn't because she is still mad at you"

Comment: ***Since then she would be nice*** isn't very idiomatic, to say the least (I'm sure atast *some* people would say it's syntactically invalid). Consider an alternative such as ***After that / From then on, she was always pleasant***.

Comment: ...and it's not good to keep repeating ***would*** in your second sentence. Once is enough to indicate that you're talking about the *habitual* past: *And when she **came** back home with her tired children, she **would** crouch for a while and **say** that she **loved** them*

Comment: @WeatherVane ok, thank you both :)